# Angular4: change event on input not working when triggered by data-binding

Tags: angular, typescript, events, attributes

Why isn't angular firing my (change) event???

I have an array with categories in it. Every category has a id, name, clean_name and checked (boolean) field. All the categories are displayed in a treeview with checkboxes. The checkboxes are looking like this:

```
<input class="categoryBox" type="checkbox" name="category"
       [value]="item['value']"
       [id]="item['clean_category_name'] + '_' + item['id'] + '_' + componentName"
       [checked]="item.checked"
       (change)="onCheckboxClick(item)">
```

So when the checkbox value is changed, it should fire the (change) event en execute the function onCheckboxClick().

When I click on the checkbox the (change) event is fired and everything works fine. But when I change the checked value in the array by code it is not fired (even though the checkbox is checked because of the [checked]="item.checked" attribute-binding). WHY IS THAT???? Doesn't angular allow me to fire (change) programmatically? Is there a solution?

I also tried with (ngModelChange) but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `[attr.xxx]` syntax when interacting with Attributes via Property Binding. You aren't actually changing the `checked` attribute of the element. I am kind of surprised you aren't getting errors in your console. So in your case it would be:

`<input class="categoryBox" type="checkbox" name="category"
       [attr.value]="item['value']"
       [attr.id]="item['clean_category_name'] + '_' + item['id'] + '_' + componentName"
       [attr.checked]="item.checked"
       (change)="onCheckboxClick(item)">`

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the reply. But when I use [attr.checked] of [attr.id] it doesn't work anymore. The id won't even show up in the code.

Comment: Can you post your component code? It's really hard to tell without any access to the logic driving the view.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="Check(id,$event)" name="id" value="{{id}}">
```

component.ts:

```
Check(value, event) 
    { if (event.target.checked)
    { this.checked.push(value); }

    else if (!event.target.checked)
    { let indexx = this.checked.indexOf(value);
      this.checked.splice(indexx, 1);}
   }
```

I did this thing in my project.

Check() functions get checkbox value which is id of user which I want and then push it in array and I use that array to perform operations on it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But my problem is that the (chech) event is nog even fired, so the Check function will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a solution to the problem, but I don't think angular 4 is capable of doing what I want. So the thing I did was to execute the function dispatchEvent on the checkbox input and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try (input) instead of (change) for me it works fine